# Customize Rally Global Api Key

Tags: rally

We see that Rally Api key can be generated with either full access or read only access. However, we are looking for the key to be customized in a way that although the key will have full access - read, write and update, it should not be able to delete any entry across the project workspace. This needs to be a global key having access to all projects to perform this kind of activity. Can you let us know if this is a feasible option and the steps to create such a key.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Agile Central to set permissions in this way.  This is true of the API Key or permissions of users logging in via the interface.

You may post this as a Feature Request or search for similar requests at https://ideas.rallydev.com/